# Django 2.2 : Is there any way to remove app name from admin urls?

Tags: python, django, routes, django-urls, django-2.2

I am using Django Built-in Admin panel, is there any way to remove app name from  urls?

If I want to access User listing, it redirects me to `27.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/` can I make it `27.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/` without the app name `auth`?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to have that? Did you consider the side-effects?

Comment: As I have the requirements, I have multiple apps in the project, which is being called by their own prefix/app names.

Comment: I have around 10 CRUD operations which consists on single Model, instead creating separate app for all, I have created single app named `common`. now all urls are followed by `common` i.e `admin/common/country`, `admin/common/city`, `admin/common/settings`.....etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class) you can create a custom `AdminSite` and override the `get_urls` method. This simple code should to the job:

In your common.admin.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def get_urls(self):
        urlpatterns = super().get_urls()
        for model, model_admin in self._registry.items():
            urlpatterns += [
                path('%s/' % (model._meta.model_name), include(model_admin.urls)),
            ]
        return urlpatterns


my_admin = MyAdminSite('My Admin')

my_admin.register(YourModel)
...
```

Note that you register your models with the new custom `AdminSite` instance.

Then in your projects urls.py

```
from common.admin import my_admin as admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.urls),
    # Your other patterns
]
```